# My for loop doesn't get the values

Tags: python, django

Here's what I have:

```
result = defaultdict(<type 'list'>,
{'USA': [{'username': 'user123', 'first-name': 'John', 'last-name': 'Doe'}],
 'Europe': [{'username': 'myname654', 'first-name': 'Peter', 'last-name': 'Johnson'}]
})
```

Here's the output I want to get

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1> USA </h1>
    <p> user123, John Doe</p>

    <h1> Europe </h1>
    <p> myname654, Peter Johnson</p> 
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried tons of different for loops, but none of them worked.

Here's what I have, but it doesn't work.

```
{% for item in result %}
<h1> {{ item }} </h1>
<p> {{ result.item.username }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you are trying to use for your for loop?

Comment: What for loop? This contains no question.

Comment: How is this not working?  Providing an error? (If so, what?)  Or just not outputting what you expect?  Admittedly, I don't know django, so maybe I'm missing something.  However, it looks to me like the for loop you provide would not print everything you expect out of result.  Maybe you left some code out in the interest of brevity, or maybe that's the problem.  Please consider showing more code.

Comment: It's not even providing an error. To clear up some confusion, I provided the for loop I'm currently using in the template.

Answer (score 1):

Result is a dictionary. Iterating through a dictionary with `for x in mydict` just gives the keys, not the values. So you need to do `{% for item, value in mydict.items %}`.

Secondly, `{{ result.item.username }}` makes no sense at all. `item` is a the value of a key into the `result` dict, but you can't do that sort of indirect lookups in Django templates. However, luckily we have the value in the `value` variable.

Thirdly, as Kabie points out, each `value` is actually a single-element list. So you'll need to access the first item in that list, and then the `username` member of that.

Putting it all together:

```
{% for item, value in result.items %}
<h1> {{ item }} </h1>
<p> {{ value.0.username }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `print` to get output in your for loop. This first converts the object to a string. Apparently the objects in this case is some sort of xml/html objects.

From inside the Django template, you don't print. You could try converting the objects to string via a `str()` call, but in general I have the feeling you are trying to make the templates do something that you shouldn't make templates to in the first place.

Try having a method on the model object that returns the string you want, and inserting that into the template instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the line:

```
<p> {{ result.item.username }} </p>
```

should be:

```
<p> {{ result.item.0.username }} </p>
```